# Longer retreat thailand

Tags: retreat

Wondering if anyone could please give me some recommendations for a longer retreat in Thailand. A lot seem to only be 10 days but I'd like to do longer now as Ive done many shorter ones and would like to go a bit deeper. Im not young and need my own room. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there are any *retreat centres* in Thailand offering long term retreats. However, many *monasteries* in Thailand are willing to offer you your own hut ('kuti'). In the monastic environment, often, you must join in the morning & evening monastic activities of chanting & meditation and also do some daily chores; while having the free time to practice on your own. You can try writing to:

- [Wat Pah Nanachat](https://www.watpahnanachat.org/about) (please read their information page & instructions carefully).
- [Wat Phu Khong Tong](http://www.forestdhammatalks.org/en/contact.php)

While you cannot write to Suan Mokkh, after they get to know you (while you stay in an open dormitory), [Suan Mokkh](https://www.suanmokkh-idh.org/idh-wat.html) or their ancillary monastery Dawn Kiem (if it is still functioning) may offer you a hut (kuti). A relatively recent post about Dawn Kiem is [here](https://www.dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?p=526063#p526063). Dawn Kiem is a 5 minute walk from the [Inter­national Dharma Her­mit­age](https://www.suanmokkh-idh.org/index.html). Suan Mokkh has a monthly 10 day retreat at its [Inter­national Dharma Her­mit­age](https://www.suanmokkh-idh.org/index.html). Therefore, if you are offered a hut, you can do formal retreat for 10 days and do personal retreat for 20 days.